# Derivative of an activation function $\tanh$ related to the sigmoid function

Tags: calculus

I have the following function (an activation function):

$$\tanh(x) = 2\sigma(2x) - 1 $$

And $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function, defined as:

$$\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

I want to calculate the derivative of the activation function with respect to $x$, so I have tried this:

$$\frac{d}{du}\tanh u = 1-\tanh^2u$$

Making a substitution in $u$ (which is: $2\sigma(2x)-1$):

$$1 - \tanh^2 u = 1-\left(\frac{e^{2\sigma(2x)-1} - e^{-2\sigma(2x)-1}} {e^{2\sigma(2x)-1} + e^{-2\sigma(2x)-1}}\right)^2$$

Then I tried to create some variables to hold the expression $a = e^{2\sigma(2x)-1}$ and
$b = e^{-2\sigma(2x)-1}$ so the formula now is:

$$ 1- \left(\frac{a - b}{a + b}\right)^2 $$

But from here I'm stuck, in how to relate the sigmoid function and the tanh function as defined, with respect to $x$. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a typo in your definition of the function? Or what does $\sigma2(x)$ mean?

Comment: Hello @Patricio, yes, it was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: What do you actually want? Why is your last line not the final answer?

Comment: You write the incomplete "I want to calculate the derivative of the activation function".  It is incomplete because you do not specify with respect to which variable you want the derivative.  If you want the derivative with respect to $u$, with which you immediately follow the quote, you are done.  If you want the derivative with respect to $x$, you are lacking the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) term ($\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}x$) to transition from the derivative you write to the derivative you want.

Comment: Hello @EricTowers, thanks for the feedback, in effect I want the derivative with respect to x. Let me edit the question to address the weakness.

Comment: So, ..., in what way is your first display not the answer to "how to relate the sigmoid function and the tanh function as defined, with respect to x."

Comment: Hello @EricTowers, in this case the first display might not be the answer since I can't figure out how to differentiate $tanh()=2\sigma(2)−1$, please advise what procedure to follow.

Comment: Nothing in "how to relate the sigmoid function and the tanh function as defined, with respect to x." mentions derivatives, so it is unclear why you are talking about derivatives.  I do not think you have clearly stated the desired type of result.

Comment: Hi @EricTowers, that's strange since in the title of my question it mentions "derivative". Do you recommend that I change the title's question?

Comment: I recommend that you clearly state what you are seeking.  It is a good idea to *also* have a clear title -- but the body of the question should actually contain the question.